# Is Chirrut in a relationship with Baze Malbus?

Tags: character, star-wars, rogue-one

I read from one of the creator's interviews that in thousands of galaxies there has to be gay relationships. He didn't mention anything about Chirrut and Baze from *Rogue One*, but I hear throughout the internet suggesting that they are a gay couple.

Is there any proof to these statements, like statements from the filmmakers, the actors, or any other external material?

Comment: Heard it throughout the internet.... *sigh*. Sources would be good.

Comment: Not sure why this has down votes. Yes, I also saw the interview where one of the creators of Rogue One, responded to the exact same question by mentioning that in a vast galaxy it shouldn't be odd to find people who are gay. He also mentioned star wars was about being inclusive, and wanted to include people of all backgrounds. But, that's about all the proof there is. The creators don't say no, but they also don't exactly say yes. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 11):

According to *Rogue One* director, Gareth Edwards, He has [admitted](https://uk.movies.yahoo.com/rogue-one-are-chirrut-and-base-a-couple-143845191.html) that he is happy for fans to read into a potential love interest between Chirrut and Baze:

> I don’t mind people reading into [Chirrut and Baze’s relationship]
>
> I think that’s all good. Who knows? You’d have to speak to them.

Ben Mendelsohn, who plays Death Star overseer Orson Krennic, says he’s happy that people are able to interpret the film how they want:

> I found them thoroughly enjoyable. Any [gay] subtext, I think, is
>   certainly… people like to enjoy these films on many different levels,
>   and if people are enjoying it on that level – that’s it. That’s what
>   you pay your ten bucks for, as it were, so good for them.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @steelersquirrel's answer, the dynamic between Chirrut and Baze comes from what inspired George in The Hidden Fortress. As per [words](https://www.inverse.com/article/25173-rogue-one-chirrut-imwe-baze-malbus-star-wars) by Lucasfilm President Kathleen Kennedy,

> **Lucasfilm President Kathleen Kennedy** has said the dynamic between Chirrut and Baze comes from what inspired George in The Hidden Fortress, referring to the great Akira Kurosawa movie. “You could even say to some extent its, you know, R2 and C-3PO, a little bit of that.”

Jiang Wen, who portrayed Baze Malbus, [says](https://moviepilot.com/posts/4001489)

> "**He and me was a partner** and he believe of course, believe in Force. But my character don’t believe Force at that time. But I pretend all of them, not them, just them, to do very, very big mission. I cannot say that. And when this guy dead, I do something better. Maybe I believe, by my action, he’s thinker, I’m doer."

So, they were just partners.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are in a relationship. Partners in crime. A friendship developed as part of being monks in the Guardians of the Whills on Jedha.

There has been ***zero confirmation, or denial***, of them being gay or otherwise not straight, by any production staff at this time. All they do is attempt to pander to LGBTQ crowds without committing to it. Plenty of "go right ahead and think that". Pure Queer Baiting nonsense.